# PHP / FaceBook API - returning hometown and location

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to store the hometown and location from Facebook API but I'm having problems extracting the data from the hometown and location arrays. (I already have token permission for that)

```
"hometown": {
    "id": "210336945633449",
    "name": "xxxx, yyyyy"
```

I'm using the following code

```
function getUserData() {
        $fb_cookie = $this->getCookie();
        if($fb_cookie) {
            $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token='.$this->getAccessToken();
            $data = json_decode($this->getDataFromUrl($url));
            $fb['id'] = $data->id;
            $fb['name'] = $data->name;
            $fb['first_name'] = $data->first_name;
            $fb['last_name'] = $data->last_name;
            $fb['link'] = $data->link;
            $fb['birthday'] = $data->birthday;
            $fb['gender'] = $data->gender;
            $fb['email'] = $data->email;
            $fb['location'] = $data->location; // <-----
$fb['hometown'] = $data->hometown; // <-----
            $fb['timezone'] = $data->timezone;
            $fb['locale'] = $data->locale;
            $fb['updated_time'] = $data->updated_time;
            $fb['picture'] = 'http://graph.facebook.com/'.$data->id.'/picture';


            //tokens
            $fb['token'] = $fb_cookie['access_token'];
            $fb['token_expires'] = $fb_cookie['expires'];
            return $fb;
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me figure this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As location and hometown are also object you to use like this get these values.

```
$fb['location'] = $data->location->name;
$fb['hometown'] = $data->hometown->name;
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the location name, try:

```
$loc=$data->getLocation();
$loc_name=$loc->getName();
```

The code above applies to Facebook SDK v4. (PHP 5.4.0 or higher is requiref for this SDK)